# Mariadb : Configure ODBC with ODBCConf.exe

Tags: windows, batch-file, odbc, mariadb

I try to configure MariaDB ODBC Connector with ODBCConf.exe

I use the commande line and this command :

> ODBCConf.exe /A {CONFIGDSN "MariaDB ODBC 2.0 Driver" "DSN=DB_Name|Server=localhost|Port=3306|User=root|Password=pwdRoot|Database=db_n}

When I run this, I have a Window who ask me to create a new Data Source to MariaDB. The name of the DB is set with the **DSN** parameters but the others parametres are not considered.

I want to make a silent configuration.

Comment: Looks like there is a closing double quote missing, are there any error msgs on the command line?

Comment: I have this same problem. How did you do the silent installation?